# How to Minimise the Size of the Dynamically Loaded Polar Area Chart of ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm using Polar Area Chart of ChartJS.
I'm loading chart dynamically.

```js
 const chartData = [
        [10, 20, 30],
        [20, 30, 40],
        [30, 40, 50]
    ];

    // Loop through the chart data and create a chart for each
    for (let i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
        debugger;
        // Create a canvas element with a unique ID
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id = `chart-${i}`;
        canvas.style.width = '100px';
        canvas.style.height = '100px';

        // Add the canvas to the page
        const chartContainer = document.getElementById('chart-containerpolar');
        chartContainer.appendChild(canvas);

        // Create a new Chart object for the canvas
        const chart = new Chart(canvas, {
            type: 'polarArea',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data: chartData[i],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "rgb(68, 114, 197)",
                        "rgb(255, 191, 0)",
                        "rgb(104, 163, 68)"
                        //'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        //'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        //'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                }],
                labels: ['Part1', 'Part2', 'Part3']
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
               /* maintainAspectRatio: false,*/
                scale: {
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div id="chart-containerpolar"></div>
```

How can I reduce the size of canvas with width="100px" height="100px".
I tried everything but chart loaded with default values.
I tried  **maintainAspectRatio: false** but chart get disappeared after that.

Comment: Maybe you can try to set  responsive: false. In this it should use the size of the canvas that you decided.

Comment: **method no 1.** (recommended, see the link in @geekyorion's post) use divs as @geekyorion said, but dynamic -- for each chart create a div, set that div's `style.height` and `style.width` (not the canvas's), append the canvas to the div and the div to the overall container; **method no 2** (less reliable) -- set canvas's `style.maxWidth` and `style.maxHeight`, `width` and `height` are overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CharJS resize/render canvas relative to it's parent container. So if you want to decrease the size of the canvas then you just need to decrease the size of it's container.

for more info please look for this [documentation guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note) for responsiveness

Here is the modified code (modification is only in `.html` file)

```js
const chartData = [
        [10, 20, 30],
        [20, 30, 40],
        [30, 40, 50]
    ];

    // Loop through the chart data and create a chart for each
    for (let i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
        debugger;
        // Create a canvas element with a unique ID
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id = `chart-${i}`;
        canvas.style.width = '100px';
        canvas.style.height = '100px';

        // Add the canvas to the page
        const chartContainer = document.getElementById('chart-containerpolar');
        chartContainer.appendChild(canvas);

        // Create a new Chart object for the canvas
        const chart = new Chart(canvas, {
            type: 'polarArea',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data: chartData[i],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "rgb(68, 114, 197)",
                        "rgb(255, 191, 0)",
                        "rgb(104, 163, 68)"
                        //'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        //'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        //'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                }],
                labels: ['Part1', 'Part2', 'Part3']
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
               /* maintainAspectRatio: false,*/
                scale: {
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div id="chart-containerpolar" style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>

<!-- You need to make sure that container has the proper size and width so that chart canvas can take the size relatively to it's parent -->
```